# The meaning of "Four to one, bar one."

Tags: meaning

> A refrain that seemed to dominate all the air, uttering its message
>   again ang again; and it said: **"Four to one, bar one."** From this Mona
>   knew that the races were beginning.

This is from "The Story pf Mona Sheehy" by Lord Dunsany.    
I don't understand the meaning of "Four to one, bar one."  
Mona was beside a roulette. And the race should be a horse race. "Four to one" means a odds? "bar one" means a horse gate?  
I am glad somebody would kindly teach me.

Comment: Four to one is definitely odds, as you say. **bar one** normally means "except one*, for example, "All of the staff were present, bar one", would mean that one staff member was not present. I don't know what it would mean in a gambling context though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, JavaLatte! It is so helpful.

Answer (score 4):

When said about a race, "four to one bar one" means that the odds for all of the horses are four to one or better, except for ("bar") one horse, the favourite.

> **bar** A preposition meaning 'except', probably derived from the verb bar in the sense `to exclude from consideration, set aside,' The
>   betting usages are bar one, as in '5/1 bar one', meaning that all
>   horses in the race, with the exception of the favourite, are being
>   offered at a price of 5/1 or better (also bar two, etc.); or, more
>   simply, bar on its own, as in '20/1 bar', meaning that all the other
>   horses whose prices have not been given are on offer at 20/1 or
>   better. The OED's first attestation is from Hotten's 1860 Dictionary
>   of Slang, where he identifies it as 'in common use in the
>   betting-ring: "I bet against the field bar two."'

[The Language of Horse Racing](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kbEFDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22bar%20one%22%20meaning%20horse%20racing&source=bl&ots=K74hDiCd58&sig=ACfU3U2XxHzkjGQmS9xigsU2rx4Nvfwl1A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8-vna6MbpAhUWTBUIHdYkDcIQ6AEwA3oECCwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bar%20one%22%20meaning%20horse%20racing&f=false)

> PREPOSITION British Except for.
>
> ‘his kids were all gone now, bar one’
>
> 1.1 Horse Racing
>   Except the horses indicated (used when stating the odds).

[Bar (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bar)